# Why $(this) always return document when use short function ()=> {}

Tags: javascript, jquery

my jQuery not work and $(this)  refers to document

```js
$(function(){
  $('.delete').on('click', (e)=> {
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
  });

  // or

  $('.delete').click( (e)=> {
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
  });
});
```

So I try this and it works because $(this) refers to true element:

```js
$('.delete').click( function () {
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
});

// or 

$('.delete').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).data('id'), $(this).val());
});
```

What is the reason for that?

Comment: This is expected, the arrow function in JS `=>` is not equivalent to a traditional function, as the context of  `this` is different. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: "What is the reason for that?" — Because treating `this` differently is 90% of the point of arrow functions existing.

Comment: You can get the element you expect from `e.target` in both types of functions, and not worry about `this` any more.